# How to configure memcached on CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, memcached

I want to use memcached on my website

I successfully installed memcached and its running on ubuntu.. i put this code in my core.php `Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'Memcache'));`

Then i got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine default is not properly configured.' in /var/www/frameworks/cakephp-2.4.4/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 181
```

What am i missing? Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'Memcache'));
```

Goes in bootstrap.php. Also, make sure the php extension for memcache is installed

Comment: I still got the fatal error.. I followed this instruction on how to install http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.installation.php

Comment: Memcache != Memcached